# Endian conversion of signed types (of PostGreSQL values)

Tags: c++, postgresql, endianness, signed

*Please excuse if this question is already answered somewhere, but since I have nearly no knowledge about big/little endian yet, nor about PostGreSQL, I do not know how to search for an answer.*

In the code I am working with, we use the PostGreSQL database and the libpq client to access our database via the binary format. PostGreSQL uses big-endian. Thus, we have to convert the query results from libpq from big- to host-endian (little-endian in our case).

The code for this looks like this

```
result = PQgetvalue( res, i, i_fnum );
//int16_t val = be16toh( *((uint16_t *)result ); //***
```

and `res` is a int16 in big-endian obtained by a call to `PQexecParams()`.

In my understanding, there is a cast missing in line `***` and the line should be

```
int16_t val = *((int16_t *)&be16toh( *((uint16_t *)result ) ); //***
```

otherwise, negative values are read incorrectly and we have implementation defined behaviour.

*I doubt that the problem is PostGreSQL specific, but the chance it is, so I try to describe the whole setting.*

---

Edit: In the comments I read that my cast makes no sense in C++. Nevertheless, the problem I have is: how do I tell the compiler to interpret the bit pattern returned from be16toh as signed type instead of unsigned type.

In various questions/anwers on stackoverflow I read the following:

- `reinterpret_cast` is not possible and yields undefined behaviour
- `static_cast` must keep the numeric value the same if possible. If not possible, it is implementation defined behaviour.

Thus, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Taking an address of something (assuming that it's possible in the first place) and then immediately dereferencing it does absolutely nothing whatsoever. C++ does not work this way. The first usage of `be16toh` is correct. Whatever your problem is, it's either something else and not what you think it is, or a better explanation is needed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have a typo in my question. There should be a cast to `int16_t`.

Comment: If there's a typo, then what's preventing you from [edit]ing and fixing it? As is the question is still not making any sense. Whether there is or is not a cast, taking the return address of a value returned by a function only works when the function returns a reference. be16toh does not. C++ does not work this way.